# R data.table group by and iterate by two columns

Tags: r, group-by, iteration, data.table

I am new to R and trying to solve the following problem:

There is a table with two columns `books` and `readers` of these books, where `books` and `readers` are book and reader IDs, respectively :

```
> books = c (1,2,3,1,1,2)
> readers = c(30, 10, 20, 20, 10, 30)
> bt = data.table(books, readers)
> bt
   books readers
1:     1      30
2:     2      10
3:     3      20
4:     1      20
5:     1      10
6:     2      30
```

For each book pair I  need to count number of readers who read both of these books, with this algoritm:

```
for each book
  for each reader of the book
    for each other_book in books of the reader
      increment common_reader_count ((book, other_book), cnt)
```

To implement the above algorithm I need to group this data into two lists: 1) a book list containing readers of each book and 2) readers list, containing books read by each reader, such as:

```
> bookList = list( 
+ list(1, list(30, 20, 10)),
+         list(2, list(10, 30)),
+         list(3, list(20))
+       )
> 
> readerList = list (
+ list(30, list(1,2)),
+ list(20, list(3,1)),
+ list(10, list(2,1))
+ )
>
```

Questions:

1) What functions to use to build these lists from a book table?

2) From `bookList` and `readerList` how to generate  book pairs with number of readers who read both of these books? For the `bt` book table described above, result should be:

```
((1, 2), 2)
((1,3), 1)
((2,3), 0)
```

Order of books in pair does not matter, so, for example `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` should be reduced to either one.

Please advise functions and data sructures to solve this. Thanks!

**Update:**

Idealy as a result I need to get a matrix with book id's both as rows and columns. Intersection is a count of readers that read both of the books in the pair. So for the above example matrix should be:

```
books | 1 | 2 | 3 |
   1  | 1 | 2 | 1 |
   2  | 2 | 1 | 0 |
   3  | 1 | 0 | 1 |

   Which means:

   book 1 and 2 are read together by 2 readers 
   book 1 and 3 are read together by 1 reader
   book 2 and 3 are read together by 0 readers
```

How to build such a matrix?

Comment: Shouldn't the 1-1, 2-2, 3-3 be the number of readers for each book (i.e. 3, 2, 1 respectively)?

Comment: When providing code, it's nicer if it's copy-paste-able, you know, without the `>` and `+` at the start of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
combs <- combn(unique(books), 2)# Generate combos of books
setkey(bt, books)
both.read <-bt[                 # Cartesian join all combos to our data
  data.table(books=c(combs), combo.id=c(col(combs))), allow.cartesian=T
][,
  .(                            # For each combo, figure out how many readers show up twice, meaning they've read both books
    read.both=sum(duplicated(readers)), 
    book1=min(books), book2=max(books)
  ),
  by=combo.id
]
dcast.data.table(               # dcast to desired format
  both.read, book1 ~ book2, value.var="read.both", fun.aggregate=sum
)
```

Produces:

```
   book1 2 3
1:     1 2 1
2:     2 0 0
```

Note by design this only does non-equivalent combinations (i.e. we don't show books 1-2 and 2-1, only 1-2, since they are the same).

Comment: Looks great, thanks! I am new to R, so a little overwhelmed by functions used. Where to read about `allow.cartesian` and `dcast` ?

Comment: for `allow.cartesian` see `?data.table`.  for `dcast` see `?dcast.data.table` and `?reshape2::dcast`.  Also, to make this easier to understand run each step separately (i.e. run `bt[data.table(books=c(combs), combo.id=c(col(combs))), allow.cartesian=T]` first, then add the next step, etc.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand the whole thing if you could verbaly describe the idea behind your solution, including intermdiate steps. I am  trying to understand each separate step from the code, but it is hard without  clear understanding  what  should be achieved on each step. Thanks!

Comment: @zork, there is a fair bit to explain here.  Maybe you can start by reading the intro data.table **[vignette](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html)**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
## gives you a seperate list for each book
list_bookls <- split(bt$readers, books)

## gives you a seperate list for each reader
list_readers <- split(bt$books, readers)
```

another form of output with the output as a data.table and giving the number of books read by each reader and the number of books each reader reads:

```
bt[ , .("N Books" = length(unique(books))), by = readers]
bt[ , .("N Readers" = length(unique(readers))), by = readers]
```

for the second part of your question I would use the following:

```
bt2 <- bt[ , .N, by = .(readers, books)]
library(tidyr)
spread(bt2, key = books, value = "N", fill = 0)
```

Output is a table that gives 1 if the books is read by reader X and 0 otherwise:

```
   readers 1 2 3
1:      10 1 1 0
2:      20 1 0 1
3:      30 1 1 0
```

Comment: Your `data.table code` isn't producing the same result as the base functions.

Comment: I know, thats why I wrote "the same with the output as a data.table", the second form makes more sense, but OP mentioned wanting the output as a list..

Comment: The layout isn't all that's different. The information given is different.

Comment: you are right, I edited it to make it more clear, thanks! I think more ways to use the data are useful here, because OP said "Please advise functions and data sructures to solve this. Thanks!"

Comment: Nice. I'm writing an expression to see if different combinations of books were read, as requested by the OP.

Comment: do that, I have no idea how to do it the exact way OP wants it, so eager to learn

Comment: I added an answer. Check it out.

Comment: Note this does not answer OP's clarified question.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a base R solution to test if the pairs were read. Someone else can add one for `data.table` if you absolutely need to use it:

```
books = c (1,2,3,1,1,2)
readers = c(30, 10, 20, 20, 10, 30)
bks = data.frame(books, readers)

cmb <- combn(unique(books), 2)
cmb <- t(cmb)
combos <- as.data.frame(cmb)
bktbl <- t(table(bks))

for (i in 1:nrow(bktbl)) {
  x[i] <- sum(bktbl[i, cmb[i, 1]], bktbl[i, cmb[i, 2]])
  combos$PairRead <- ifelse(x > 1,"yes", "no")
}
combos
  V1 V2 PairRead
1  1  2      yes
2  1  3      yes
3  2  3       no
```

Comment: Please, see my question update - I need number of times books in the pair were read together, and not the flag `read_together`